# what elliptic specific curve is needed?

Tags: mqtt, tls1.2, x509, azure-iot-hub, mbed

**mqtt** CONNECTACK fails after handshake success, using ECC x509 with **mbed** TLS

I am trying to connect to IoT Hub using an STM32 board.
I have a simulated project using Linux with the exact same CA-signed trusted and device certificates to ensure the problem is not on the certs or the server configuration.
The Linux device connects fine (it uses OpenSSL as chipper)

But for my embedded device STM32 I am using the **mbedTLS** stack.

with traces enabled, I see the 15 handshake steps occur, then the I get the following error:

```
IoTHub Connection Status = IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONNECTION_UNAUTHENTICATED, Reason = IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONNECTION_DEVICE_DISABLED
ERROR: mqtt_operation_complete_callback L#1616
Connection Not Accepted: 0x5: Not Authorized
```

The **reason** looks suspicious to me, but server side, the device is enabled and looking at the source code, the only response is that the server rejected the connection.

Because I ruled out certificates, server settings and transport, I am assuming that my problem is with the Chipper.

Q1) Any idea what specific curve is needed?

```
//#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP192R1_ENABLED
//#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP224R1_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP256R1_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP384R1_ENABLED
//#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP521R1_ENABLED
//#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP192K1_ENABLED
//#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP224K1_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP256K1_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_BP256R1_ENABLED
#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_BP384R1_ENABLED
//#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_BP512R1_ENABLED
//#define MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_CURVE25519_ENABLED
```

Q2) What traces can I enabled to understand why the server is rejecting the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/coisme/Mbed-to-Azure-IoT-Hub claims that it's working with Azure IoT Hub and the only thing it enables on top of default config is `MBEDTLS_SHA1_C`.

Answer (score 0):

Azure IoT C SDK have a port for MBED, reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-c-shared-utility/blob/1d622902d7842f94193fc394987f2b4e978bb700/adapters/tlsio_mbedtls.c